# What is the best and efficient approach to write a inner join in apache beam?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

suppose my query is: "select b.* from `sourav_test.test1` a inner join `sourav_test.test2` b on a.id=b.id". I need the best and efficient approach for apache beam to write this.

Comment: If your input datasource happens to be BigQuery, it might be more efficient to perform the join within BigQuery before pulling it into beam/dataflow.

Answer (score 0):

In Apache Beam SDK 2.5 a great approach is using the [join library](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/javadoc/2.5.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/extensions/joinlibrary/Join.html) which performs SQL like joins. In the case of inner joins, the syntax would be as follows:

```
innerJoin(PCollection<KV<K,V1>> leftCollection,PCollection<KV<K,V2>> rightCollection)
```

Relating to your case, the left and side collections represents the collections to be inner joined. The K value would be the type of the key related to both collections. The Vs would represent the values of each collection respectively.